# Magento 1.9.2.3 cannot show products on homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

I tried the code:-

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" category_id="7" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

On my CMS > page but the products of the categories are not coming instead, it is breaking the homepage. Can Any one provide me the full procedure to add products of specific category on my homepage (cms page) in Magento 1.9.2.3